# Check which files are currently being used using a windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I'm trying to make a batch script to check each file in a directory and wait if one of them is currently being used by a process in windows. This solution is based on [this answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542831/133001). The objective is to execute the following script in Jenkins before deploying an application using MSDeploy to make sure no dll is being used in the application folder:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\Folder\%1\*.dll /b') do (
:TestFile
ren C:\Folder\%1\%%A C:\Folder\%1\%%A
IF errorlevel 0 GOTO Continue
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul
GOTO TestFile
:Continue
)
```

However when running this script, either as a stand-alone or through a Jenkins Windows Command step, it shows the following error when executing the FOR loop:

```
Warning: ) was unexpected at this time.
```

What could be the reason behind this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `goto` breaks the loop context of `for`, so place the content of the `for` loop as a subroutine at the end of the script and use `call` to execute that; do not forget to put `exit /B` affter the `for` loop to not fall into the subroutine unintentionally after having finished loop iterations...

Comment: Also take a look at [`handle` utility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32673397/3959875).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `goto` breaks the loop context of `for`; that causes the error you described. To work around that, you could move the code from the body of `for` into a subroutine at the end of the batch script and use `call` to execute it for each loop iteration. An `exit /B` is necessary after the `for` loop to not fall into the subroutine unintentionally after the loop has finished iterating.

Another issue is the error check for the `ren` command, because the condition `if ErrorLevel 0` is true for an `ErrorLevel` equal to *and* greater than `0`; so the logic needs to be changed to `if not ErrorLevel 1`, which is true if `ErrorLevel` is less than `1`.

Here is the fixed code (you will notice, that I put some quotes around paths, and that I used the `~` modifier for some parameters; this has been done to guarantee that no problems arise with paths containing *spaces* or some other special characters):

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B "C:\Folder\%~1\*.dll"') do (
    rem the processed items of the original code are passed as arguments:
    call :TestFile "%~1" "%%~A"
)
exit /B

:TestFile
rem the delivered arguments can be accessed by `%1` and `%2` here:
2> nul ren "C:\Folder\%~1\%~2" "%~2"
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :EOF
> nul ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5
goto :TestFile
```

The redirection `2> nul` at the `ren` command avoids any error messages to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. I wasn't aware of how contexts worked when using goto in batch.